# Appending items to javafx GridPane on event

Tags: java, javafx-2

I have an application that uses the javafx GridPane layout manager, with one button affixed to it. Currently when I click on the button, I have it call a function and write to command line the result.

What I'm wondering is instead of writing to command line, how could I instead send the result of my function call to the grid itself, displaying it in say a text field or what have you? Currently this is the code that creates the UI

```
GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(0, 25, 0, 25));

Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Get Button");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {                
                      String result = staticClass.getData(1, "A");
                      System.out.println(result );
            }
        });

        grid.add(btn, 0, 0;
```

Comment: what about using `ListView` ?

Comment: @tarrsalah Would that work? Right now I'm up for anything as long as I can place returned data where I want too on the UI.

Comment: Add a label to the gridpane and set its text on button action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that to perform what I was after, you need to use the setText method, which I believe is what Uluk Biy was alluding too in his comments. For those that run into the same issue as I did down the road, here's a code sample to help illustrate.

```
final Label textDisplayLabel = new Label();

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {                
                textDisplayLabel.setText(calcTime.getTimestampDiff(new DateTime(1976, 9, 11, 10, 59, 0, 0), new DateTime(2012, 11, 11, 10, 59, 0, 0))); 
            }
        });
```

then just place textDisplayLabel to where you want it on the UI and viola.